# Form fields validation fails but they are not in the form

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig, symfony5

I am building a Form with classes. When submitting the form I get validation errors for 2 fields I never even send.

**Entity:**

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="lastvisit_date", type="datetime")
     * @Assert\DateTime()
     */
    private $lastvisitDate;
```

The other field looks the same.

After submitting the Form those 2 fields are marked as wrong when doing:

**Controller:**

```
$form->handleRequest($request);   // this catches 2 validation errors for fields missing in $request
```

**Template-Dump of form.errors :**
[image: Validation error]

To my understanding only fields sent with the form should be validated, not random other fields.

Why is this happening and how to get rid of those fields?? I do not even define them in the form.

Comment: As soon as you want to persist an entity, all entity assertions should be valid. If some properties are calculated, you should use a DTO, a Form with a Model then transform the model into an entity.
Look at this tutorial: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-forms/form-dto

Comment: And if I simply want to neglect some fields? Do I have to insert them in the $request as if they were sent? Is that state-of-the-art in symfony?

Comment: You don't need to send them to the form if they are not being used.  But they still need to have valid values when you set a constraint on them.  The validation system is actually independent of the form system.  It's not even a question of entity persistence.  Either initialize the values, change the validation rules or use a different data object for your forms.  You might also want to look into group validations which allows you to control which validations are used.

Comment: So you are saying this problem should not occur and points to the possibility that the database-data is wrong and that is why the validation fails, regardless of the form?

Comment: @Jonathan Not sure who your last comment was directed to but, assuming it was me then yes I am saying that your entity properties need to have valid values.  If you are pulling your entity from the database and lastvisit is set to null then that is indeed a problem.  It could be that all you need to do is to modify the validation rule and allow null or date.

Comment: Okay now I understand. ALthough the value seems to be correct. I may look into that direction. Thank you !

Comment: @Cerad Actually I just want to edit fields that occur in a form. And do not touch those values of the fields not being sent. Though ALL fields are being validated no matter of their occurence. If I tie the form to the entity it should actually know that missing fields are not missing but left off and should not be considered. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You are still not quite grasping the fact that the form is not doing the validation but rather an independent validation service.  The service just gets told to validate the entity.  It neither knows nor cares about the form.  The real mystery here is why you want entities to have invalid properties?  In any event you can either remove the validation from the entity or send a different object to the form.

Comment: To be clear: I want to edit a User but I dont need a 'register_date' in the edit form, though it fails validation because of a missing registerDate. I do `$form->isValid()`, which fails, why has this nothing to do with the form?

Comment: Nevermind, I have the issue:
used `@Assert\Datetime`
instead of `@Assert\Type("DateTimeInterface")`